# PS/2 Keyboard powers on my PC

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, desktop-computer

I hope this is correct place to post this question.

My keyboard broke, so I have temporarily replaced it with an old keyboard with a PS/2 connector. When I power off my PC it can now be turned on by pressing any key on the keyboard. I have checked the APM settings in the BIOS which are all set to disabled. Is there another BIOS setting which may be causing this issue?

Requested:

- Windows 10
- ASUSTek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your APM settings are either missing or have "Power on by PS/2 keyboard" disabled, your best bet is to disable other power saving / wake up settings.

For example, Windows 8 and onward tend to boot with PS/2 keyboard even if all BIOS settings are turned off, **if** "fast boot", "fast startup" or similar options are enabled in BIOS. This is because of "hybrid shutdown technology" the OS uses.

[How to disable Fast Startup Windows 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/243901/the-pros-and-cons-of-windows-10s-fast-startup-mode/)

Answer (score -1):

You should try to shut down your pc fully because I have a ps/2 keyboard plugged in and it doesn’t do the same thing.